# AWS - How to monitor using aws-sdk?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I want to use aws-sdk to monitor the activity arround an AWS account and return it's object consumption. How should I start?

Comment: What constitutes "activity"? And by "object consumption", are you referring to the downloading of S3 objects?

Answer (score 2):

Activity and consumption metrics can be monitored using Cloudwatch.

```
var cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

var params = {
  Dimensions: [
    {
      Name: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      Value: 'STRING_VALUE'
    },
    /* more items */
  ],
  MetricName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Namespace: 'STRING_VALUE',
  NextToken: 'STRING_VALUE'
};

cloudwatch.getMetricWidgetImage(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});

cloudwatch.listMetrics(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#listMetrics-property

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html#s3-request-cloudwatch-metrics